# How to import data from a csv or xlsx file when row names have ñ or accents in R?

Tags: r, database, csv, ggplot2, import

I want to do some plots using R with RStudio but there are columns in my data written in Spanish, for example, "Año" (Year), "Número de desastres naturales registrados" (Number of reported natural disasters), so when I want to import the CSV file I have problems like this:

```r
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Año' not found
```

All this is for the special characters.

```
type <- read_csv("C:/Users/Alonso/Desktop/Tesis_MGII/Avance_mayo/escrito/natural-disasters-by-type.csv",fileEncoding="utf-8")
View(type)
```

The data and row names will be used to make some plots using ggplot2 library, but nothing works and I have to write my document 100% in Spanish, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the encoding option "Latin-1" standard (also known as ISO 8859-1 or ISO/IEC 8859-1).

```
library(data.table)
type <- fread(file.path("C:/Users/Alonso/Desktop/Tesis_MGII/Avance_mayo/escrito/natural-disasters-by-type.csv", encoding = "Latin-1"))
```

Comment: This was the right way to solve the problem. I just had to set the encoding en Window-1252 ! Thanks, you give me the right hint.

Comment: Yes, `Window-1252` format is also widely used for encoding from Spanish. I really like the following encoding recommendation table for different languages, maybe you will come in handy too: https://scratchpad.fandom.com/wiki/Character_Encoding_Recommendation_for_Languages

Answer (score 0):

Use the encoding option inside your read.csv code.

Following code sample is working for me:

```
file <- textConnection("# ---------------------
# 
# ---------------------
Año, Número
2001, 3152
2002, 3200
2003, 3500
2004, 3700
2005, 3850
2006, 4200", encoding = c("UTF-8"))
file

# read data from textConnection 
desaster <- read.csv(file, skip=3, head=TRUE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE, sep=",", encoding="UTF-8")
desaster
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: `read_csv` imports columns with row names and column names in Spanish for me without specifying any encoding and `ggplot2` is able to graph them. The defaults should be UTF-8 and perfectly capable of handling Spanish special characters. You do not even need to add backticks ``. Unfortunately the the reprex add-in I normally use does not recognise those same characters!

If you're on Windows, make sure you are saving as UTF-8 `.csv` and it should all work.

Comment: I was thinking the same but is not like that :(, I've used all the answers that you all give me and the problem is not fixed :(